# Can you export a bibtex file from zotero with links?

Tags: citations, reference-managers, latex

I have most of the papers I use often in Zotero. Before I learnt about it, I would always format my manually typed citations with \href and company such that you could click on the reference and go to the original link I got the paper from. I would disable formatting so the document looked like there were no links, but it helped me and others navigate the references more easily.

I am wondering if there is a way to configure Zotero such that when it exports a bibtex file, it also adds a reference to the stored URL.

Also, sorry if this is off topic, I am not sure where to ask, since it's not a programming, super user or latex question per se.

Comment: Don't you get it when you export the library by default? File->Export Library->BibTeX? Also works for individual references.

Comment: I do get the url in the bibtex entry, but the resulting pdf does not have a clickable element that takes you to the associated url.

Comment: So are you asking how to ensure the URL is displayed when compiling the tex file?

Comment: @GoodDeeds more than displayed, I want the reference to be clickable so that you can go to the URL of the original article in the easiest way possible.

Comment: If the url field is contained in the bibtex file you should just need to load the hyperref package in the tex file, unless you're using some unusual bibliography style. See e.g. [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100782/128923).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549309/bibtex-how-to-link-to-the-source